# how to group out different ip address and count their total numbers in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

Hello Splunk network developers

```
source="logfile" host="whatever" sourcetye="snort" | search "ip server"
```

Gives all events related to particular ip address, but I would like to group my destination ipaddresses and count their totals based on different groups.

```
Ex 
COUNT   SCR IP         DST IP
100 192.168.10.1:23 -> 4.4.4.4
20  192.168.10.1:23 -> 5.5.5.5
10  192.168.10.1:23 -> 6.6.6.6
```

I have uploaded my log file and it was not able to really recognize the host and source ip address. With this particular situation, if you can help me to add ways to group different dst adds and count them. I would be really happy.

However, if you can help me to upload the log file that can recognize the source and host ipaddress that would be easier for me, but please help me to give me your instruction if you happen to know.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF9Ka.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to come down to you how you group your [`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats) calls:

```
| stats count(src_ip) by dst_ip
```

will be different from

```
| stats count(dst_ip) by src_ip
```

will be different from

```
| stats count by dst_ip src_ip
```

will be different from

```
| stats count by src_ip dst_ip
```

What are you actually trying to accomplish?